# Selecting a specific item in a FOR loop

Tags: javascript

I know this is a simple questing, but I am learning JavaScript. I want to grab the first item in the FOR loop and the grab the second one as well. Is there a way to do this. I only need three random items from the shuffled array.

```
/**
 * Created by the JavaScript Development Team
 * Class: PWA
 * Goal: Goal7
 */

(function () {
    var names = ["walker", 'marisa', 'annie', 'gizmo', 'marvin'];
    function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
        for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };
    myArray = shuffle(names);
    console.log(myArray);
    var Person = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        console.log(this.name);
        //        for(i=0; i< names.length; i++){
        //            var person =[new Person(names[i])];
        //        }
    };
    console.log('hello');
    var i = 0;
    var length = myArray.length = 3
    while (i < length) {
        //console.log(myArray[i]);
        var person = new Person(myArray[i]);
        //        var person = [new Person(names[i])];
        i++;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
for (var i=0; i++; i < names.length; i++) {
       if (i==1) {
          //grab
       }
       else if (i==2) {
          //grab
       }
       else {
          //Do more
       }
}
```

Or even better: `names[0]` is the first one in the array and `names[1]` is the second one. No need to loop through it really if that is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
for(var i = 2; i >=0; i--) {
    new Person(myArray[i]);
}
```

but honestly, why do you need to loop if you know how many items you want and the items have already been randomized?

Answer (score 0):

use break in while loop:

```
(function () {
        var names = ["walker", 'marisa', 'annie', 'gizmo', 'marvin'];
        function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
            for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        };
        myArray = shuffle(names);
        console.log(myArray);
        var Person = function (name) {
            this.name = name;
            console.log(this.name);
            //        for(i=0; i< names.length; i++){
            //            var person =[new Person(names[i])];
            //        }
        };
        console.log('hello');
        var i = 0;
        var length = myArray.length = 3
        while (i < length) {
            //console.log(myArray[i]);
            var person = new Person(myArray[i]);
            //        var person = [new Person(names[i])];
              if(i == 2){ break; } // <==
            i++;
        }
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're over complicating this a bit. Why would you want to shuffle all the names if you just want three random ones? I wrote up some code for you that's a little clearer I think.

```
(function () {

    var people = ['walker', 'marisa', 'annie', 'gizmo', 'marvin'];

    var random_people_to_get = 3;
    var random_people = [];

    var Person = function (name) { this.name = name; };


    for( var i = 0; i < random_people_to_get; i++ ){

      // Grabbing a random name from people and removing it!
      var random_name = people.splice( Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length), 1)[0];

      // Make the random_name into a person and put it into the random_people array!
      random_people.push(new Person(random_name));

    }

    console.log(random_people);

})();
```

If you want to stick at your way you can make an array with the first three items by using `slice`. Just like:

```
var firstThreeRandomNames = myArray.slice(0, 3);
```